An improved version of "to sphere" in geometry nodes
I need an improved version of the To Sphere tool. The existing tool does its job well, but it does not adjust the distance between vertices at all.

With the new ability to turn geometry nodes into tools, and the new "selected" node, this should be possible.
I have already seen averaging the distance between vertices in the "retopology tool" on the official Blender website.
So if you are strong in geometric nodes, please make an improved analogue "to the sphere", if it is too difficult, then at least "to the ring" with the ability to choose the alignment axis.
UPD:
The vertices I'm talking about are almost always part of other geometry, so I mentioned the "Selected" nodes and the ability to create tools from nodes so that other vertices are not rounded.
A little more clarity on what I want to achieve:


//EDIT: Sorry, I misread your question. Why are you using To Sphere? This is just a circle, so I would use Loop Tools > Circle for this.
When I'm doing this on a similar mesh like yours in the second example, I get exactly what I expect. Have you enabled the Regular option in the tool? If this is not the issue, you might upload an example mesh to your question to check where the problem lies.


The problem lies in my not quite reasonable addonophobia. Instead, I really like the flexibility of geometry nodes, which is why I insist on them in the question. I need exactly what you showed, but through geometry nodes. I understand that this is a rather difficult task, so I'm waiting for when I can announce a bounty for its completion.

Okay... addonophobia, so you do not use any addons, not even the official Blender addons (like LoopTools)? Not even Cycles? Well, okay then I cannot answer the question. Although in this case I do not really see the flexibility advantage of GN here, since you would have to define which vertices exactly you want to make circular and I could imagine that for something like an arm sleeve you might probably need to apply the mesh afterwards anyway... but maybe someone finds a good way in GN.

I need the selected vertices to be aligned in a correct ring with equal distances between the points (a sphere is possible if a ring is not possible) relative to their averaged center relative to the selected axis (Selecting an axis can now also be implemented via Geometry Nodes) Also, I have seen a similar solution in the Retopology Tool (Which is actually the Geometry Nodes tool).

There are definitely some complex node setups out there, and I'm no expert, but you could achieve something as simple as this by using the Resample Curve node which automatically spaces the vertices evenly. Temporarily increase the number of vertices to a high number like 100 or 1000 for more resolution, then transform it to a sphere, and finally set it back to the original number of vertices. For those who don't know, you can also use LoopTools by RMB > LoopTools > Space.

Take note that this is only a simple example and is limited to 2D geometry without faces. And the geometry origin needs to be at the center.

I apologize for the inaccurate explanation. I meant vertices that are part of a larger mesh. For example, make the "arm sleeve" round (I updated the question). Thanks for the tip about Loop Tulles, I didn't know about them, but what I need is geometry nodes. Is it possible to update your example so that only the selected vertices are rounded and not separated from the main mesh?
